# runOnUpdateThread in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

Could anyone explain exactly what this method does in AndEngine?

```
runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    // to safely detach and re-attach the sprites
    public void run() {

}


});
```

EDIT:

To be more specific, the runOnUpdateThread in general

Comment: You mean specifically with an empty `run()` method? Or are you asking about `runOnUpdateThread` in general?

Comment: Sorry, runOnUpdateThread in general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an Engine method that executes the Runnable when the engine is updating the scene. All scene updates must happen on the update thread (just as all rendering must happen on the UI thread). This method can be used from outside the update thread to make a change to the contents of the scene.

Comment: @coder_For_Life22 Yes. Or to detach an entity, etc. Note that according to [this thread](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles1/runonupdatethread-t6434.html) there is a bug (or design flaw) where if you call `runOnUpdateThread` when you are already running on the update thread, the runnable won't be executed. Just something to be aware of.