# What should we use for background processing in Andengine Game?

Tags: android, timer, andengine, background-task

I have a code (the for Loop) which runs every 1 Second. I am using TimerHandler for this.
I am using do while loop and I have to find which objects are invisible and make them visible randomly, because number of objects to make visible changes with time. I am using do while loop to select random object. But the problem is that do while loop may take long time (because it is selecting values randomly) to find all the invisible objects randomly and during that time TimerHandler may call the for Loop Again.
I want to know if there is any way to do that task in background so that it keeps on running in background and I make the invisible objects visible from there.

My code is

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i ++){
        if(i != playerSpriteNo{
            if(!sprite[i].isVisible()){
                do{
                    randomValue = MathUtils.random(0, 15);
                }while((playerSpriteNo == playerSpriteNo) && (sprite[i].isVisible()));

                sprite[i].setVisible(true);
            }
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `TimerHandler` triggers from the `Engine#UpdateThread` thread. Execution (`TimerHandler` task) triggers in the `Engine#UpdateThread` thread as well. So it's impossible that your `TimerHandler` execution task triggers twice (or more) times simultaneously.
2. It seems fine to use the `TimerHandler` for that. If you have a lot of objects - it can really block the thread, so you can do your random stuff to improve it.
3. Still, you can run another thread but you have to update the sprite visibility in [`runOnUpdateThread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889610/runonupdatethread-in-andengine) only (don't be confused with Android `runOnUiThread()`)

Comment: Thanks Yaroslav Havrylovych, I will use 3rd option, it seems suitable and will update.